# Azure Container Registry error getting credentials

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, azure-container-registry

I was following the tutorial [Continuous deployment with Jenkins and Azure Container Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/jenkins-continuous-deployment?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fjenkins%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#deploy-jenkins-to-vm) To integrate Jenkins on Azure and set it up to work with my container registry and kubernetes.

Manually, I run the commands for creating the resource group. These [commands](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/jenkins-tutorial/deploy-jenkins-vm.sh) (starting from line 10).

The command on line 26:

`az vm extension set --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --version 2.0 --name CustomScript --vm-name $virtualMachine --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/master/jenkins-tutorial/config-jenkins.sh"],"commandToExecute": "./config-jenkins.sh"}`'

, executes the following [script](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/jenkins-tutorial/config-jenkins.sh):

```
    # Jenkins
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y

# Docker
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y

# Azure CLI
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 417A0893
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install azure-cli

# Kubectl
cd /tmp/
sudo curl -kLO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

# Configure access
usermod -aG docker jenkins
usermod -aG docker azureuser
sudo touch /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
service jenkins restart
```

But I think that some configuration impacted my container registry, because I am not able to log in

> $ az acr login --name myContainerRegistry error getting
>   credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase
>   you entered is not correct.`

But I can access other information from azure

```
$ az acr list --resource-group ResourceTest --query "[].{acrLoginServer:loginServer}" --output table
AcrLoginServer
----------------------------------
mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io
containerregistryah.azurecr.io
```

In some forums I read that is related with Docker, but I wonder, from Azure which changes should I do ? Should I delete the new Jenkins installation?

Comment: Does `docker login` work for you? Please try to use `docker login xxx.azurecr.io -u xxxxx -p password` to login it.

Comment: do I need to create a service principal? , which -u username and -p password, should I use?

Comment: No, you can find the username and password in Azure portal. container registry -> access keys.

Comment: I see, I didn´t know and created a new one, should I delete it andreas-mbp:~ amhg$ az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalAH --password mypssd

Comment: You want to use AAD to login ACR?

Comment: I just tried this docker login containerregistryah.azurecr.io -u containerRegistryAH -p password, I got the same error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169830/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-andreahg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a macos issue, please follow this article to do [it](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3625).

> Try opening Keychain Access.app. Right-click on the login keychain and
>   try locking it and then unlocking it again.

Comment: The problem was: when running the command az acr login --name myContainerR . I got the message:
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.`

Comment: Could you please login ACR with `--password` and `-u` for test? like this :`az acr login -n myContainerRegistry -u xxxx -p xxxx`